# The packages are installed with pecl but are not displayed in phpinfo()

Tags: php, nginx, centos, pecl, centos8

I use centos and php 7.3.2 and Nginx web server

I have installed several packages using pecl. They are all installed successfully.
When I run command "pecl list" or "php -m", I see the name of the desired packages:

```
Package  Version State
PDO_IBM  1.5.0   stable
apcu     5.1.21  stable
ibm_db2  2.1.5   stable
igbinary 3.2.7   stable
raphf    2.0.1   stable
```

I have also checked the php version related to CLI with phpinfo() function. Both of them are one.

I have also run the "pecl config-show" command. Its php path is correct

I have also checked the following values. CLI and phpinfo() are the same

```
PHP API     20180731
PHP Extension   20180731
Zend Extension  320180731
```

However, I cannot see the installed modules on the phpinfo() page. And their functions don't work either

Comment: i believe you should explicitly call the extension in your php.ini, like so: `extension="mongodb.so"` , usually pecl before zend in my case. In some installations, php.ini is different for cli and SAPI and php-fpm. Make certain that if you fix one, you fix'em'all

Comment: how do you fix the issue ?? I've faced the same issue..